# Iam unable to set values to formArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to set values to form Array,i am unable to set new values.

I have tried to set values using patch value,but failed

```
//in component.ts
this.packageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: ['', Validators.required],
  productImage: ['', Validators.required],
  price: ['', Validators.required],
  products: this.formBuilder.array([
    this.addProductFormGroup()
  ])
})

//form builder Array
addProductFormGroup(): FormGroup {
 return this.formBuilder.group({
  productNames: ['',Validators.required],
  productQuantities: ['',Validators.required]
})
}

 //adding row
addProductsRow() 
{
 (<FormArray>this.packageForm.get('products'))
 .push(this.addProductFormGroup();
}

//deleting row
 removeProductsRow(productGroupIndex: number) {  
 (<FormArray>this.packageForm.get('products'))
 .removeAt(productGroupIndex);
}

addPackage() {
this.productNames=null;
this.productQuantities=null;
this.packageForm.value.products.forEach(element => {
  this.productNames = (this.productNames == null) ? element.productNames 
   : this.productNames + "~" + element.productNames;
   this.productQuantities = (this.productQuantities == null) ? 
  element.productQuantities : this.productQuantities + "~" + 
   element.productQuantities;
  });
}
```

i'm getting values from form with this click event `addPackage()`,I want 
to send form data in this format `productNames`as [oil~sugar~flour] and 
`productQuantity` as [4~3~5].

Comment: Question is not clear, can u elaborate the question and what you need to get ?

Comment: hi sudhakar,i want to change the values of "productNames" and "productQuntity"  as  [oil~sugar~flour]  and  [4~3~5] before sending it to service file. i'm getting data from form like this array `0:{productNames: "oil", productQuantities: "4"}
1: {productNames: "sugar", productQuantities: "3"}
2: {productNames: "flour", productQuantities: "5"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  addPackage() {
    const data = this.packageForm.getRawValue();
    this.productNames = data.products.map(e => e.productNames).join('~');
    this.productQuantities = data.products.map(e => e.productQuantities).join('~')
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmczgr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  private addPackage() {
    const productNames = [];
    const productQuantities = [];

    this.packageForm.value.products.forEach(element => {
      productNames.push(element.productNames);
      productQuantities.push(element.productQuantities);
    });

    return {
      productNames: '[' + productNames.join('~') + ']', 
      productQuantities: '[' + productQuantities.join('~') + ']'
    };
  }
```

Inside your onSubmit handler you can create a new object that will be sent to your backend api. Something like this:

```
onSubmit() {
    const obj = this.addPackage();

    console.log(obj.productNames);
    console.log(obj.productQuantities);

    const dataToSend = {
      ...obj,
      title: this.packageForm.controls.title.value,
      price: this.packageForm.controls.price.value
    };

    // send this object to the backend API
    console.log(dataToSend)

  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akcgwf).

Comment: hi robert,thanks for your contribution . `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addPackage()">Submit</button>` up on clicking this button i'm getting form data how to use onSubmit(),can we use addPackage() and onSubmit() at the same time

Comment: Yes, you can.  Add submit button like this: `<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>`, and in your TS file call addPackage from onSubmit method.